# Angular Karma Jasmine - Shows 100% Code Coverage Report with 0 testcases tested

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am using Angular with Karma Jasmine. And I am trying to get Code coverage. But I am getting below code coverage always:

[image]

Getting similar error in Pipeline :
[image]

if you notice in the image it was able to detect only polyfill.ts file.

Not sure why its not able to show full list of files and its code coverage.. :(

**Command used** :
ng test --codeCoverage=true --watch=false

**Angular, Jasmine , Karma Version**:

```
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "json-server": "^0.15.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.3",
```

**Karma.conf.js**:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html



module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine", "@angular-devkit/build-angular"],
    plugins: [
      require("karma-jasmine"),
      require("karma-junit-reporter"),
      require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
      require("karma-phantomjs-launcher"),
      require("karma-jasmine-html-reporter"),
      require("karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter"),
      require("@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma"),
      require('./custom-karma-pluggins/describe-tracker'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: "coverage",
      outputFile: "TEST-results-karma.xml",
      suite: "",
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require("path").join(__dirname, "./coverage/universal-ap"),
      reports: ["html", "lcovonly", "text-summary", "cobertura"],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    reporters: ["describeTracker", "progress", "junit", "kjhtml"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["Chrome"],
    captureTimeOut: 210000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 210000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 210000,
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

I tried searching same on the internet and tried out the solution suggested like:

- to make changes in kamra config file. Which I tried different version provided online.
- To check the 'sourceRoot' in angular.json file. Which looks fine as it points to path where all the code file exist 'Src'
- To make changes in package.json's command.
- To make autowatch or singleRun true.

None of these worked for me.

**Edit:**
**Angular.json** :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "universal-ap": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "ax",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles"
              ]
            },
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/flexboxgrid/css/flexboxgrid.min.css",
              "node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles/themes/ax-brand-theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3.7mb",
                  "maximumError": "3.7mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "10kb",
                  "maximumError": "40kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ax": {
              "assets": [
                {
                  "glob": "web.config",
                  "input": "src/config",
                  "output": "./"
                },
                {
                  "glob": "*.json",
                  "input": "src/config",
                  "output": "./config"
                },
                "src/favicon.ico",
                {
                  "glob": "**/*",
                  "input": "src/assets",
                  "ignore": [
                    "**/whitelabel/**/*"
                  ],
                  "output": "/assets"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "universal-ap:build:ax"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "universal-ap:build:ax"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "universal-ap:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/config"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles"
              ]
            },
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/flexboxgrid/css/flexboxgrid.min.css",
              "node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles/themes/ax-brand-theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "universal-ap:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "universal-ap:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "universal-ap",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Please note, if I use fdescribe, I am able to get code coverage for that specific file:
[image]

Comment: how does your `angular.json` file look like?

Comment: Hi @WenW, I have added the angular Json file. Can you please help me understand how angular.json file impact the code coverage.
As far as I know only 'sourceRoot' propertie's value is being used. 
Is there any other property value that can impact code coverage. ?

Comment: I'm assuming you have the `test.ts` file mentioned in your angular.json? `"main": "src/test.ts",`

Comment: Yes its mentioned

Comment: so you have this file in your src? https://github.com/SantiagoGdaR/angular4-unit-test/blob/master/src/test.ts ?? line 28 is the code that finds all your spec files.

Comment: Yes I have the test.ts file. All the code exists except below three lines:
declare const __karma__: any;
__karma__.loaded = function () {};
__karma__.start();

I believe that should not be the problem since this file was created years back. and the issue started around a  month or so back

Comment: try adding 'coverage' in your the karma file `    reporters: ["describeTracker", "progress", "junit", "kjhtml","coverage"],`

Comment: Hi, I tried adding 'coverage'. but got below error:
Can not load reporter "coverage", it is not registered!
Do I need to import anything?

Comment: try installing karma-coverage, and adding it to your karma config file.

Comment: Hi @WenW, Tried installing karma-coverage and require in karma config file.
But it didnt help. Same issue again, getting (100/100) coverage

Comment: I just you start over with this guide: https://angular.io/guide/testing